Custom Generic SwiftUI Picker View
In our visionOS app we are currently using a segmented Picker to allow the user to switch the current tool (among other things). It is important to us to have different tooltips for each button, which the current native Picker doesn't allow for. We have implemented a custom picker using HStack and some buttons (see Inset Style for View).
We are now attempting to make the view generic so we can use it in multiple places with different data models.
Here is the current code using a hardcoded data model:
HStack {
    ForEach(ToolType.allCases, id: \.self) { toolType in
        Button {
            toolManager.tool = toolType
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: toolType.iconName())
        }
        .buttonStyle(PickerButtonStyle(isSelected: toolType == toolManager.tool))
        .tag(toolType)
        .help(toolType.name())
    }
}
.frame(height: 44)
.padding(.horizontal, 4)
.background {
    ZStack {
        Capsule()
            .fill()
        Capsule()
            .fill(.shadow(.inner(color: .white, radius: 1, x: 0, y: 0)))
            .mask {
                LinearGradient(
                    colors: [.clear, .black],
                    startPoint: UnitPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.7),
                    endPoint: UnitPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.9)
                )
            }
        Capsule()
            .fill(.shadow(.inner(color: .black.opacity(0.5), radius: 2, x: 0, y: 1)))
            .mask {
                LinearGradient(
                    colors: [.black, .clear],
                    startPoint: UnitPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.1),
                    endPoint: UnitPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.6)
                )
            }
    }
    .foregroundStyle(Color(white: 0.4))
}

struct PickerButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    let isSelected: Bool
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .foregroundStyle(isSelected ? .white : .gray)
            .frame(width: 44, height: 36)
            .background {
                if isSelected {
                    Capsule()
                        .fill(Color(white: 0.5))
                        .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.3), radius: 1, x: 1, y: 1)
                }
            }
            .contentShape(Capsule())
            .hoverEffect()
    }
}


As you can see, it is using the ToolType enumeration and the ToolManager.tool property to keep track of the selected tool.
Ideally, I would like to be able to do this:
CustomSegmentedPicker(selection: $toolManager.tool) {
    ForEach(ToolType.allCases, id: \.self) { toolType in
        Image(systemName: toolType.iconName())
            .tag(toolType)
            .help(toolType.name())
    }
}

I've got a partial solution that draws the buttons correctly, but I am unable to access the tag/help properties in order to manage the selection:
struct CustomSegmentedPicker<SelectionValue, Content>: View where SelectionValue: Hashable, Content: View {
    @Binding var selection: SelectionValue
    @ViewBuilder var content: Content

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(subviews: content) { subview in
                Button {
                    //How to set the binding value here?
                    //selection = subview.tag
                } label: {
                    subview
                }
                //How to know if the current subview is selected?
                //.buttonStyle(PickerButtonStyle(isSelected: subview.tag == selection.wrappedValue))
                //.tag(subview.tag)
                //.help() //Anyway to get what was passed to .help in the subview?
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 44)
        .padding(.horizontal, 4)
        .background {
            //Same code as previously posted...
        }
    }
}

I'm sure I could make this work by passing in an array of objects that conforms to a protocol allowing me to access the name and image name, but I'm hoping to make this a drop in replacement for the native Picker.
EDIT:
In response to the similar answer, not all of the data models being used in the Picker can conform to CaseIterable. For example, at run time we load (and potentially modify) an array of dataset objects, and a Picker is used to select which one is loaded.
